# Error when inserting data into MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '16:45:40, 2012-12-18 16:45:40, Renovated Stone house in Perast, first line, 2012' at line 1
```

This is the SQL query where the problem is

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_title`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `xml_id`)";
$sql .= " VALUES ({$postAuthor}, {$postDate}, {$postDate}, {$title}, {$postModified}, {$postModified}, {$xmlId});";
```

Comment: You need to sanitize your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values have to be enclosed in quotation marks, and you have to make sure that there are no quotation marks in the values.

The best way to do this is using prepared statements, e.g. with the [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$sql .= " VALUES ({$postAuthor}, {$postDate}, {$postDate}, {$title}, {$postModified}, {$postModified}, {$xmlId});";
```

Should be:

```
$sql .= " VALUES ('$postAuthor', '$postDate', '$postDate', '$title', '$postModified', '$postModified', '$xmlId')";
```

Remove the wrapped: ', where the column type isn't a varchar.

Also, you must validate you're escaping the special characters inside the variables. [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Or at least you have to escape the variables before.

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_title`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `xml_id`)";
$sql .= " VALUES ('$postAuthor', '$postDate', '$postDate', '$title', '$postModified', '$postModified', '$xmlId')";
```